# how to use javascript to get jsf h:outputText value?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, backing-beans

I have a button has action which can set myBackingBean.myString, and onclick event calls js method to alert that value. I just want to get the value of myString from backing bean by using javascript.

I have a hidden output which has value from backing bean:

```
h:outputText id="myOutput" rendered="false" value="#{myBackingBean.myString}"
```

then I need to alert this value in javascript fxn which triggered by a button:

```
function myFunction() {

var outPut= document.getElementById("myForm:myOutput").value;

...

}
```

but i got `Object required` error. How can i fix this?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you sure that the h:outputText is rendered (rendered="false" could just not add it to the DOM. If it does not render, it can't be accessed. If you need it hidden, use h:inputHidden instead).

Then make sure that it renders an HTML tag as  or  acting like a container with the id attribute as "myForm:myOutput".

Also, the .value javascript accesor is used for input tags, so use inerHTML instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply but could you please give me more details? I have a button has action which can set myBackingBean.myString, and onclick event calls this js method. I just want to get the value of myString from backing bean, so I thought this hidden output could help. I modified ouputText to h:inputHidden id="hidden1" value="#{myBackingBean.myString}" but get same error. also i changed .value to .innerHTML did not work

Comment: Can you inspect the HTML generated? Just to be sure the input type hidden is there and that it has the required value?

Comment: <input id="myForm:hidden1" type="hidden" value="" name="myForm::hidden1"> i inspect elements and i have this line. is that what you mean?

Comment: Yeap, this `document.getElementById("myForm:hidden1").value` should work (at least, no javascript error is generated). But that input hidden has an empty value, so, make sure the `#{myBackingBean.myString}` binding is right and is changing the input hidden value.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But now I have one more question. my button triggers this js and also calls a method from backing bean. the backing bean set this hidden input's value (#{myBackingBean.myString}), but jsf UI gets the value before i click the button, so first time it is null and second time will be the value set in the bean. so how can I update the value ?

Comment: You could try this http://bit.ly/JjKKGn using commandButton instead on commandLink (or if you can, try with the commandLink).

Answer (score 0):

You need not always to have a hidden field to access the Bean Property. You can do it as below.

```
<h:commandButton value="Show" onclick="alert('#{myBackingBean.myString}');"/>
```

But if you want to change the value of '**myString**' when you click the button and then you want to display the new value you should use a `<a4j:commandButton/>` and it's **onComplete** attribute as below.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Change" action="#{myBackingBean.changeString()}" oncomplete="alert('#{myBackingBean.myString}');" />
```

Comment: Thank. I tried the second one but even rerender the hidden input the value did not get updated. now it seems impossible to update the client side value. is it possible to use alert to show the facemessages? I have context.addMessage(FacesMessage.FACES_MESSAGES, message); in my backing bean, then how can i use js to alert this msg?